# Error adding xmlns atribute to a starter tag in a XML using C#

Tags: c#, xml, xmlwriter, visual-c#-express-2010

Good afternoon. I have issues adding a especific atributes to 2 starter tags in a xml using c#. The 2 tags should look like this:

```
<EnvioDTE xmlns="http://www.sii.cl/SiiDte"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          version="1.0"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sii.cl/SiiDte EnvioDTE_v10.xsd">

<SetDTE xmlns="http://www.sii.cl/SiiDte"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        ID="SetDoc">
```

But the result is this:

```
<EnvioDTE xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sii.cl/SiiDte EnvioDTE_v10.xsd"
          version="1.0"
          xmlns="http://www.sii.cl/SiiDte">

  <SetDTE xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          ID="SetDoc">
```

The code i'm using to generate the xml is this:

```
public void dtebasico()
{
    var doc = new XDocument(new XDeclaration("1.0", "ISO-8859-1", ""));

    using (XmlWriter writer = doc.CreateWriter())
    {
        string ah = "http://www.sii.cl/SiiDte";
        writer.WriteStartDocument();
        writer.WriteStartElement("EnvioDTE", ah);

        writer.WriteAttributeString("xmlns", "xsi", null, "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
        writer.WriteAttributeString("xsi", "schemaLocation", null, "http://www.sii.cl/SiiDte EnvioDTE_v10.xsd");
        writer.WriteAttributeString("version", "1.0");

        writer.WriteStartElement("SetDTE", "http://www.sii.cl/SiiDte");
        writer.WriteAttributeString("xmlns", "xsi", null, "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
        writer.WriteAttributeString("ID", "SetDoc");
        ...

    }
    doc.Save("dte" + folio + ".xml");

}
```

Can you help me please? I'm really desperate.

Comment: Aren't the `EnvioDTE` the same, just with a different order of attributes? (which won't matter)

Comment: Child elements inherit the namespace from the parent if it was declared using the xmlns attribute. In your example, because SetDTE belongs to the same namespace as the parent XmlWriter did not write the xmlns attribute since it is not needed.

Comment: Ok i understand that.

Comment: But i want to that the xmlns atribute in the end of EnvioDte will be at the beginning of the tag, not at the end.

Comment: I don't think you can enforce that but at the same time it shouldn't matter any compliant Xml parser should be able to process the document correctly regardless of the position of the xml attribute.